# Importing Data from Dictionary Web site

Tags: c#

I need to translate a group of words from a free online dictionary, so I wrote a simple program in C# to send http requests, and then parse returned HTML to extract the meanings.

However, the free web site stops after 130 requests, asking for manual entering of words as in image (captcha ) in order to continue. how can i over come this problem?

Thanks,
Samer

Comment: write your own dictionary service that allows you to call it as many times as you want.

Comment: Search for a web service provider rather than sending requests to websites. Most of them have security measures to take care of spams and bots.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt a problem with your code, it is their website stopping itself from being spammed with hits from a single user. Easiest thing to do would be to have a dictionary of your own, then there would be no Captcha to get around.